# Trying to return the position of an element in the array, having trouble printing

Tags: java

I'm working on this code to print the position in this array, and I think I have all code correct when it comes to getting the return value, but I haven't been able to get any values to come out; print on the screen. I've tried calling the arrayLength method to print but all I get is the error "arrayLength cannot be resolved to a variable" . So I'm not sure what variable to print.

```
 public class Generics {
        static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer[] array = {2, 4, 6, 8};
        Integer s= list.get(0);

         int arrayLength(int[] array, int value) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if(array[i]==value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(arrayLength);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code in incomplete and unreadable. Please post everything, and format it correctly. Your IDE can do that in a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You have to invoke the method from your `main`.

Comment: add `static` to `arrayLength()`method

Comment: You are trying to print a variable named `arrayLength`. While you have a method with the same name (which is allowed), they're different concepts. An identifier without parentheses is always a variable (except in de context of lambda expressions, but that's another story).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are attempting to print function instead of a returned value.
if you replace `System.out.println(arrayLength);` with `System.out.println(arrayLength(array, 4));`
it should print the index of 4 in the array

Also as mentioned in the comments the arrayLength method needs to be static to be invoked from the main method

Answer (score 0):

Note: Integer s= list.get(0); gives IndexOutOfBoundsException as list is empty so it is not possible to retrieve the first element

```
public class Generics {
        static int[] array = {2, 4, 6, 8};

        static int arrayLength(int[] array, int value) {

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                if(array[i]==value) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(arrayLength(array, 2));
            System.out.println(arrayLength(array, 4));
            System.out.println(arrayLength(array, 6));
            System.out.println(arrayLength(array, 8));
        }
    }
```